# When adding two Vector3s and assigning to an existing variable, does Unity do the addition direct to the existing variable, or create a new one?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For example:

```
Vector3 v1, v2, v3;
v1 = v2+v3;
```

What would Unity be doing internally? Would it be:

```
v1.x = v2.x+v3.x
v1.y etc, etc
```

Or:

```
Vector3 temp = new Vector3();
temp.x = v2.x+v3.x
temp.y etc, etc
v1 = temp
```

Sorry I know it's a niche question! I'm doing some optimisation and wondering if it's worth inlining all my vector math.

Answer (score 2):

Vector3 is a structure (value type as opposed to reference type), and the internal implementation is like following:

```
Vector3 v1= new Vector3(); //Not an object, memory is allocated on stack instead of on heap!
v1.x = v2.x + v3.x;
v1.y = v2.y + v3.y;
v1.z = v2.z + v3.z;
```

There is no allocation of memory on a temp structure, but directly allocate memory for the output variable and then populate its values.

Don't be confused with the new X() syntax, just like [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#, it is still a value type!

Comment: Thank you David. I actually decided to go ahead and inline all the vector math, and the profiler is showing zero GC, although the two may be unconnected. Either way I'm getting zeroes in the GC column so I'm happy :-)